# Using '==' instead of .equals for Java strings

Tags: java, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What makes reference comparison (==) work for some strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698260/what-makes-reference-comparison-work-for-some-strings-in-java)

I know this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus), but in spite of recommendations to use `.equals()` instead of the `==` comparison operator, I found that `==` works all the time:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true
```

Can anyone give me an example of the `==` operator failing?

Comment: Marcos provided a [good example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus/1251721#1251721) in an answer to the question you linked.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698260/what-makes-reference-comparison-work-for-some-strings-in-java/9698305#9698305

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is because you're lucky. The `==` operator in Java checks for *reference equality*: it returns true if the pointers are the same. It does not check for contents equality. Identical strings found at compile-time are collapsed into a single `String` instance, so it works with `String` literals, but not with strings generated at runtime.

For instance, `"Foo" == "Foo"` might work, but `"Foo" == new String("Foo")` won't, because `new String("Foo")` creates a new `String` instance, and breaks any possible pointer equality.

More importantly, *most* `Strings` you deal with in a real-world program are runtime-generated. User input in text boxes is runtime-generated. Messages received through a socket are runtime-generated. Stuff read from a file is runtime-generated. So it's very important that you use the `equals` method, and not the `==` operator, if you want to check for contents equality.

Comment: A bit of an additional note, the reason "foo" == "foo" actually works, is because all literal strings are interned http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()

Answer (score 10):

> Can anyone give me an example of the == operator failing?

Example 1:

```
String s1 = new String("Hello");
String s2 = new String("Hello");
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // false
```

Example 2:

```
Integer a=1000,b=1000;
System.out.println(a == b); // false
```

Comment: Guess that will work. But aren't Strings immutable? As such, shouldn't they be interned?

Comment: Literal strings are interned.

Comment: "Hello" == "Hello" ==> true. However, new String("Hello") will allocate some memory for an object, and the same thing again will allocate some more memory, elsewhere, for another object. Since the "==" operator compares references, it will return false.

Comment: Small Integers (-127 .. 127) are also "interned". So the Integer example would actually return true for a = 100. (this is an implementation detail, however, I would not want to rely on it).

Comment: @pessimopoppotamus - **only** String **literals** are interned automatically.  Other String instances are interned only if the application calls `String.intern()` explicitly.  (It is an efficiency thing: interning is expensive in a number of respects.)

Answer (score 4):

When you do this, you are actually creating *string literals*:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
```

The compiler finds identical string literals and then optimizes by keeping one instance in the heap and making all the variables in the stack point to it. So doing an `==` will return true because they point to the same memory address.

When you do this, you are creating *string objects*:

```
String s1 = new String("Hello");
String s2 = new String("Hello");
```

The instantiation will create unique space on the heap for each of these and the stack variables will point to those separate locations. Thus, these will be equal using `.equals()` because their values are the same, but they will not be equal using `==` because they are different objects in the heap memory space.

Answer (score 4):

Seasoned Java developers rarely if ever use `new String(String)`, but the problem arises in other cases as well.  For example:

```
String hello = "Hello"
String hell = hello.substring(0, 4);
System.err.println("Hell" == hell);  // should print "false".
```

(Most String instances in a real-world applications are formed either by taking a substring of some other String, or by constructing it from an array of characters.  Very few applications will only use String instances created as literals.)

Comment: One reason to use "y = new String(x)" (where x is a string) is to allow garbage collection, when x is a substring of a very large string. If you just use "y = x" then the very large string can't get garbage collected as long as y is referenced. If you use "new String(x)" then a new string is created that doesn't reference the original large string.

Comment: That is true, but in my experience it is rarely necessary.  And if it is not necessary, then it is actually an anti-optimization.