# Why string == "value" returns false even if its "value"?

Tags: java, string, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

User sends command "/test " to get 2 outputs:
- if password was wrong
- if password was correct

The correct password is "secret"

Why when user do "/test secret" it still returns that its wrong password?

```
@Override
    public void processCommand(ICommandSender sender, String[] args)
    {  
        if ( args.length == 1 )
        {      
            if ( args[0] != "secret" ) {
                sender.sendChatToPlayer("Wrong password " + sender.getCommandSenderName() );
            } else {
                sender.sendChatToPlayer("Welcome " + sender.getCommandSenderName() );
            }
        } else if ( args.length == 0 ) {
                sender.sendChatToPlayer("No parameters send");
        } else {
                sender.sendChatToPlayer("You have to give me just 1 argument");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a space that needs to be trimmed?

Comment: As noted by many, many other questions on this site, this is because you need to use the `.equals()` method to compare string equality in Java.

Comment: Read about equals() versus ==

Comment: You should be using `.equals()` not `==`

Comment: Pretty good answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689952/using-instead-of-equals-for-java-strings

Comment: This comes up every week

Comment: If only it was that infrequently. Can we get a close please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they are different instances. Use equals() to compare strings.

Comment: Exactly. `==` checks if two references refer to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `string.equals(other_string)` instead of `==`, which only checks they are the same object. They may not be the same object, but may still be equal. String interning may happen in Java where the two objects *are* the same, but this is not guaranteed.