# Use '==' instead of equals for string comparison in Scala

Tags: string, scala, equals

Why is it recommended to use `==` rather than `.equals` for string comparison in Scala? There are a lot of questions in StackOverflow that do not recommend the use of reference equality for String comparison in Java but why is it advised to do the exact reverse in Scala?

Comment: Scala is not Java, even though it is hosted by the JVM. More specifically, what's safe in Scala is not safe in Java.

Comment: [Whats the difference between == and .equals in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681161/whats-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-scala)

Comment: Scala aimed to iron out many of the illogical annoyances in Java. One of these were `==` vs `.equals`, it's not obvious to newcomers when to use which, so instead they decided you'd just use `==` for everything, which makes a lot more sense from a usability standpoint

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `==` is reference equality?

Comment: @JörgWMittag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689952/using-instead-of-equals-for-java-strings

Comment: That question is for a completely different programming language that has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:scala].

Comment: @JörgWMittag Okay, I understand the fact that it is a different language than Scala but stating it to have "absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with Scala" is a little far-fetched. Don't you think?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Scala, `==` is equivalent to `equals` except that it handles `null` so no `NullPointerException` is thrown.

If you want reference equality, use `eq`.

Comment: There are other minor differences between `==` and `equals`, e.g. `==` is aware of numeric equivalence: `1==1L` but `!1.equals(1L)`. In general, `==` is the reasonable operator to use unless there is an explicit reason not to do so.

Comment: True that! ``==`` is to be preferred in Scala.